# TableViewController with NSFetchedResultsController to visualize two result 'query'

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have this situation in my CoreData:

I have entity A.

I have the B entity that has as its parent entity entity A.

I have my TableViewController where I use NSFetchedResultsController to visualize the A objects.

Now, I need to visualize the A and B objects into the same TableView.

Is possible this?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch B and retrieve the As with

```
bObject.aChildren // or whatever your relationship is called
```